# Cannot ask for permissions except publish_actions what can cause this?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here are some buttons which i would like to use for getting permissions from the user at certain locations on my site. From these only the publish_actions permission works! The other are giving a blank page only.
Why? What can be the problem? I checked, all permissions are declined, so it can't be the problem that they are already granted.
(Now these buttons are at the same place in the code for testing.)

```
<? $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $url ); ?>
<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick="powindow('<?=$helper->getLoginUrl(array('user_videos'))?>&display=popup',800,600);">User videos")</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="powindow('<?=$helper->getLoginUrl(array('publish_actions' ))?>&display=popup',400,200);">Publish actions</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="powindow('<?=$helper->getLoginUrl(array('public_profile' ))?>&display=popup',400,200);">profile</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="powindow('<?=$helper->getLoginUrl(array('user_photos' ))?>&display=popup',400,200);">photo</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="powindow('<?=$helper->getLoginUrl(array('email' ))?>&display=popup',400,200);">email</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="powindow('<?=$helper->getLoginUrl(array('user_friends' ))?>&display=popup',400,200);">User friends</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using getLoginURL in a wrong way, there must be a scope parameter in the Array: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

That being said, you really should consider using the JS SDK for Login/Authorizing. It is a lot easier to handle and the recommended way.